# Among the data contained in ResponseBody, a null value is included

Tags: jpa

I would like to join two DB tables using Spring Boot JPA and respond with JSON data in a DTO.

When I request the corresponding API using PostMan
If you look at the TRACE history of the current intelliJ screen, you can see that the DB data is well contained and entered, but the json data shown in postman contains null.
[image: There are data]
[image: There are null]

DTO

```java
@Getter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class SchedulerAdminResponse {

    private List<ScheduleDTO> scheduleDto;
    private CountProcessDTO countProcessDto;

    public interface ScheduleDTO {

        Long getAdminScheduleId(); // null
        String getTitle();
        String getDescription();

        Long getUserScheduleId(); // null
        String getFullName(); // null
        Progress getProgress();
        LocalDateTime getScheduleStart(); // null
    }

    public interface CountProcessDTO {

        Integer getWaiting();
        Integer getAccepted();
        Integer getRefused();
    }
}
```

So, I checked whether there was a difference between the dto attribute and the column name SELECTed by DB Query, and the data type of the attribute.
Seeing as the data is passing through the TRACE history just fine in the first place, this is probably not the cause of the problem.

Second, I currently have two DTOs in the form of an interface in the SchedulerAdminResponse, but I wondered if this was the problem, so I declared the two DTOs separately as interfaces, pulled them out, and tried again, but I got the same result.

I share my code here.

Controller

```java
@GetMapping("/schedule/confirm/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<?> getAdminSchedulerAndUserScheduler(
        @PathVariable Long id,
        @AuthenticationPrincipal MyUserDetails myUserDetails
) {

    if(id.longValue() != myUserDetails.getUser().getId()) throw new Exception403("You do not have permission.");

    ResponseDTO<?> responseDTO = new ResponseDTO<(schedulerAdminService.getAdminScheduleDetail(id));

        return ResponseEntity.ok(responseDTO);
}
```

Service

```java
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
public SchedulerAdminResponse getAdminScheduleDetail(Long id) {

    return new SchedulerAdminResponse(
            schedulerAdminRepository.findSchedulesWithUsersById(id),
            schedulerAdminRepository.countScheduleGroupByProgressById(id)
    );
}
```

Repository

```java
@Query(value =
        "SELECT sa.id AS admin_schedule_id, sa.title, sa.description, " +
        "su.id AS user_schedule_id, su.schedule_start, su.progress, u.full_name " +
        "FROM scheduler_user_tb AS su " +
        "LEFT OUTER JOIN user_tb AS u " +
        "ON su.user_id = u.id " +
        "LEFT OUTER JOIN scheduler_admin_tb AS sa " +
        "ON sa.id = :id",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<SchedulerAdminResponse.ScheduleDTO> findSchedulesWithUsersById(Long id);

@Query(value =
        "SELECT SUM(T.WAITING) AS waiting, SUM(T.ACCEPTED) AS accepted, SUM(T.REFUSED) AS refused " +
        "FROM (" +
        "   SELECT " +
        "   CASE WHEN progress = 'WAITING' THEN COUNT(progress) END AS WAITING, " +
        "   CASE WHEN progress = 'ACCEPT' THEN COUNT(progress) END AS ACCEPTED, " +
        "   CASE WHEN progress = 'REFUSE' THEN COUNT(progress) END AS REFUSED " +
        "   FROM scheduler_user_tb WHERE scheduler_admin_id = :id GROUP BY progress) AS T",
        nativeQuery = true)
SchedulerAdminResponse.CountProcessDTO countScheduleGroupByProgressById(Long id);
```

I've searched many ways for this issue but couldn't find any issue with ResponseBody.
plz Help me..!

Because of my poor English skills, I had to use a translator.
Please forgive me if the sentence is awkward.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this problem but I still haven't realized the exact cause.

first, I changed code like this. (Repository)

```java
@Query(value =
        "SELECT sa.id AS adminScheduleId, sa.title, sa.description, " +
        "su.id AS userScheduleId, su.schedule_start AS scheduleStart, su.progress, u.full_name AS fullName " +
        "FROM scheduler_user_tb AS su " +
        "LEFT OUTER JOIN user_tb AS u " +
        "ON su.user_id = u.id " +
        "LEFT OUTER JOIN scheduler_admin_tb AS sa " +
        "ON sa.id = :id",
        nativeQuery = true)
List<SchedulerAdminResponse.ScheduleDTO> findSchedulesWithUsersById(Long id);
```

```java
public interface ScheduleDTO {

    Long getAdminScheduleId(); // null
    String getTitle(); 
    String getDescription();

    Long getUserScheduleId(); // null
    String getFullName(); // null
    Progress getProgress(); 
    LocalDateTime getScheduleStart(); // null
}
```

In Java, property values are usually used in camelCase, and in DB, snake_case is used.
When using Spring Boot JPA, I converted the difference between them,
For some reason, the conversion doesn't seem to happen in this current code.

However, this is not the case for all properties.
For example, fullName -> full_name doesn't seem to recognize the two-word case.

So, I used 'AS' in Query and directly changed the column name, which was in snake_case, to camelCase.

Previously, I thought that the data retrieved by Query contained up to DTO, but in fact, Query retrieved data properly, but it was not transferred to DTO.

Comment: If anyone has any thoughts on this issue or can explain it to me,
I would really appreciate it.
Thanks for reading and I hope this helps someone with the same problem.